# Selenium wait for PrimeFaces 4.0 ajax to process

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, selenium, primefaces

My Selenium tests need to wait for ajax requests to process to avoid race conditions. In PrimeFaces 3.5 you could use the following method to wait ([copied straight from the PrimeFaces svn repo](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/examples/trunk/showcase/src/test/java/com/prime/showcase/integration/AbstractIntegrationTest.java?r=6365)):

```
private static final String JQUERY_ACTIVE_CONNECTIONS_QUERY = "return $.active == 0;";
private static final int DEFAULT_SLEEP_TIME_IN_SECONDS = 2;
private static final int DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS = 10;

protected void waitUntilAjaxRequestCompletes() {
   new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
      .withTimeout(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
      .pollingEvery(DEFAULT_SLEEP_TIME_IN_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
      .until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
         public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
            JavascriptExecutor jsExec = (JavascriptExecutor) d;
            return (Boolean) jsExec.executeScript(JQUERY_ACTIVE_CONNECTIONS_QUERY);
         }
   });
}
```

Unfortunately this code does not work in PrimeFaces 4.0, the jQuery connections never seem to be active.

So the question is: how do I wait for PrimeFaces ajax requests to process in version 4.0?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

PrimeFaces 4.0 uses its own ajax event handler, you can use the following code:

```
private static final String JS_JQUERY_DEFINED = "return typeof jQuery != 'undefined';";
private static final String JS_PRIMEFACES_DEFINED = "return typeof PrimeFaces != 'undefined';";
private static final String JS_JQUERY_ACTIVE = "return jQuery.active != 0;";
private static final String JS_PRIMEFACES_QUEUE_NOT_EMPTY = "return !PrimeFaces.ajax.Queue.isEmpty();";

private static final int TIME_OUT_SECONDS=10;
private static final int POLLING_MILLISECONDS=500;

private void waitForJQueryAndPrimeFaces() {
   new FluentWait(driver).withTimeout(TIME_OUT_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
      .pollingEvery(POLLING_MILLISECONDS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
      .until(new Function < WebDriver, Boolean >() {
         @Override
         public Boolean apply(WebDriver input) {
            boolean ajax = false;
            boolean jQueryDefined = executeBooleanJavascript(input, JS_JQUERY_DEFINED);
            boolean primeFacesDefined = executeBooleanJavascript(input, JS_PRIMEFACES_DEFINED);

            if (jQueryDefined) {
               // jQuery is still active
               ajax |= executeBooleanJavascript(input, JS_JQUERY_ACTIVE);
            }
            if (primeFacesDefined) {
               // PrimeFaces queue isn't empty
               ajax |= executeBooleanJavascript(input, JS_PRIMEFACES_QUEUE_NOT_EMPTY);
            }

            // continue if all ajax request are processed
            return !ajax;
         }
      });
}

private boolean executeBooleanJavascript(WebDriver input, String javascript) {
   return (Boolean) ((JavascriptExecutor) input).executeScript(javascript);
}
```

Comment: What does the |= operator do?

Comment: @KorayTugay it translates to: `ajax = ajax || executeBooleanJavascript(input, JS_JQUERY_ACTIVE);`